# best-worst ranking: do all items have to be blocked together at least 1 time?

Tags: survey, ranking, methodology, rating

Here there are instructions to build Max-diff (or Best-worst) ranking questionnaire:

> In an ideal world, a MaxDiff experimental design has the following characteristics, where each alternative appears:
>
> 1. At least 3 times.
> 2. The same number of times.
> 3. With each other alternative the same number of times (e.g., each alternative appears with each other alternative twice).

(*[Source](https://www.qresearchsoftware.com/max-diff-experimental-design-q)*)

I have 25 items, that I repeat three times, and then shuffle them in such a way that they are divided into 15 blocks of 5 items in each block (I can provide here the code in R or Python, but I think it's not relevent here). So conditions (1) and (2) are met. The problem is with the condition (3):  there are cases where *i*-th and *j*-th items are not met within the same block at all.

How crucial is the violation of condition (3) for building best-worst ranking blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you violate criterion 3, you have missing information from your study - it is not counterbalanced.

25 items is rather large for a choice experiment. Can you cut down the number of items into a more manageable size? In particular, is there any item or item level that is likely to be dominant?

[This article may be of help](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1755534513700502/1-s2.0-S1755534513700502-main.pdf?_tid=cfa7e691-9980-4878-b4b6-59c2182b2562&acdnat=1524899199_c34157f205a5f66b55131329b3f108f2), in particular section 3.3.6. For example, if you have 5 items, each with 5 levels, it may be difficult for your participants to make choices.